# PnP Modern Search Web Part - isDocument works in Search Results Refinement Filters, but IsListItem doesn't

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, pnp-search-webparts

I am using latest release of PnP Modern Search as per March 2022 (v4.5.4)

Installed one week ago in a O365 Developer environment.

Trying to show list items results only in the **PnP Search Results web part**. For this, I am using the **Refinement Filters**.

If I enter **(IsDocument:equals("Yes"))** in the Refinement Filters, the results includes documents only.

However, if I enter **(IsListItem:equals("Yes"))** in the Refinement Filters, I don't get results

**Note:** If I clean the Refinement Filters and set the **Debug Layout** in the PnP Search Results web part, I get items that represents documents (*with IsListItem: "false" and IsDocument: "true"*) as well items that represent list items (with IsListItem: "true" and IsDocument: "false").

Why **(IsDocument:equals("Yes"))** in the Refinement Filters works but **(IsListItem:equals("Yes"))** doesn't? Both properties are checked in the **Selected Properties** box.